# Not getting incremental data with jdbc importer from sql to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

As per jdbc importer :

It is recommended to use timestamps in UTC for synchronization. This example fetches all product rows which has added since the last run, using a millisecond resolution column mytimestamp:

```
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : [
            {
                "statement" : "select * from \"products\" where \"mytimestamp\" > ?",
                "parameter" : [ "$metrics.lastexecutionstart" ]
            }
        ],
        "index" : "my_jdbc_index",
        "type" : "my_jdbc_type"
    }
}
```

I want to input data incrementally based on a column modified data whose format is 2015-08-20 14:52:09 also i use a scheduler which runs every minute . I tried with the value of sql key as

```
"statement" : "select * from \"products\" where \"modifiedDate\" > ?",
```

But data was not loaded.

Am I missing out something ?

Answer (score 0):

the format of lastexecutionstart like this "2016-03-27T06:37:09.165Z".
it contain 'T' and 'Z' . So that is why your data was not loaded.

If you want to know more.
here is link
https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc